# Table validation to find wrong rowspan or column value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have the below XML file in which

```
<table-wrap id="tbl4" position="float">
            <label>Table E3</label>
            <caption>
                <p></p>
            </caption>
            <alternatives>
                <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                         xlink:href="EEMCS-01-2021-001110.tif"/>
                <table frame="hsides">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                         <col align="left"/>
                         <col align="left"/>
                         <col align="left"/>
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2" align="left">1</th>
                            <th colspan="5" align="center">2</th>
                            <th rowspan="2" align="center">3</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="center">4</th>
                            <th align="center">5</th>
                            <th align="center">6</th>
                            <th align="center">7</th>
                            <th align="center">8</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>12</td>
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>14</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>16</td>
                            <td>17</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td colspan="2">22</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">23</td>
                            <td colspan="2">24</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>26</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>31</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">32</td>
                            <td colspan="2">33</td>
                            <td>34</td>
                            <td colspan="2">35</td>
                            <td rowspan="3">36</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </alternatives>
        </table-wrap>
```

I want to validate the wrong rowspan or colspan count mentioned in the XML file. Here example, "< td rowspan="3" > 36 < /td >" has rowspan="3" before the last row which is wrong. Therefore, an additional row should be generated in the final XML output. However, the output of the table was created in box format not differed now when the rowspan was mentioned wrongly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="table_with_no_rowspans">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="rowspan"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$table_with_no_rowspans/*" mode="final" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="#current" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- make sure it works for both table/tr and table/tbody/tr and table/thead/tr -->
    <xsl:template match="table/tbody | table[not(tbody | thead)] | table/thead" mode="rowspan">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="tr[1]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[2]" mode="rowspan">
                <xsl:with-param name="previousRow" select="tr[1]" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr" mode="rowspan">
        <xsl:param name="previousRow" as="element()" />

        <xsl:variable name="currentRow" select="." />

        <xsl:variable name="normalizedTDs">
            <xsl:for-each select="$previousRow/*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@rowspan &gt; 1">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@rowspan - 1" />
                            </xsl:attribute><!--
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name() = 'rowspan')]" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
                        --></xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$currentRow/*[1 + count(current()/preceding-sibling::*[not(@rowspan) or (@rowspan = 1)])]" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="newRow" as="element(tr)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$currentRow/@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$normalizedTDs" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy-of select="$newRow" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tr[1]" mode="rowspan">
            <xsl:with-param name="previousRow" select="$newRow" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td | th" mode="final">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@rowspan">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @rowspan" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used the above code but it producing table in box format and some of the values are missing in output due to wrong rowspan. Please suggest me the correct approach.

Now I get the XML output as below:

```
<table-wrap id="tbl4" position="float">
   <label/>
   <caption>
      <p/>
   </caption>
   <alternatives>
      <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
               xlink:href="EEMCS-01-2021-001110.tif"/>
      <table frame="hsides">
         <colgroup>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
         </colgroup>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th align="left">1</th>
               <th colspan="5" align="center">2</th>
               <th align="center">3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th/>
               <th align="center">4</th>
               <th/>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>9</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>11</td>
               <td>12</td>
               <td>13</td>
               <td>14</td>
               <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>16</td>
               <td/>
               <td>17</td>
               <td>18</td>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>20</td>
               <td/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>21</td>
               <td colspan="2">22</td>
               <td>23</td>
               <td colspan="2">24</td>
               <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>26</td>
               <td>27</td>
               <td/>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>29</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>32</td>
               <td colspan="2">33</td>
               <td>34</td>
               <td colspan="2">35</td>
               <td>36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td/>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>38</td>
               <td>39</td>
               <td/>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </alternatives>
</table-wrap>
```

In the last row "< tr >", entries "< td >40< /td >< td >41< /td >" are missing due wrong usage of rowspan value in "< td rowspan="3" > 36 < /td >". Similarly in "< thead >" entries "< th align="center" >6< /th > < th align="center" >7< /th > < th align="center" >8< /th > are missing in "< tbody >" entries < td >30< /td > < td >31< /td > are missing.

Expected XML output:

```
<table-wrap id="tbl4" position="float">
   <label/>
   <caption>
      <p/>
   </caption>
   <alternatives>
      <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
               xlink:href="EEMCS-01-2021-001110.tif"/>
      <table frame="hsides">
         <colgroup>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
         </colgroup>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th align="left">1</th>
               <th colspan="5" align="center">2</th>
               <th align="center">3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th/>
               <th align="center">4</th>
               <th align="center">5</th>
               <th align="center">6</th>
               <th align="center">7</th>
               <th align="center">8</th>
               <th/>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>9</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>11</td>
               <td>12</td>
               <td>13</td>
               <td>14</td>
               <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>16</td>
               <td/>
               <td>17</td>
               <td>18</td>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>20</td>
               <td/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>21</td>
               <td colspan="2">22</td>
               <td>23</td>
               <td colspan="2">24</td>
               <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>26</td>
               <td>27</td>
               <td/>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>29</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>31</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>32</td>
               <td colspan="2">33</td>
               <td>34</td>
               <td colspan="2">35</td>
               <td>36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td/>
               <td>37</td>
               <td>38</td>
               <td>39</td>
               <td/>
               <td>40</td>
               <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td/>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </alternatives>
</table-wrap>
```

I know the above expected is not a proper table but based on input  the wrong table should be generated to validate further.

Comment: Perhaps show the result you want the XSLT to produce for the sample you have shown and explain in plain English what the task at hand is, with a detailed enough specification that someone can help to implement it in XSLT. Also explain and show precisely in what way the shown code produces the wrong result, e.g. which "values are missing".

Comment: From the description, I don't understand why "36" is the wrong value.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen and al.truisme Now I explained in detail about missing values and wrong usage in the description and also added the expected output

Comment: @Rupesh_Kr plz guide me on this